# How to order laravel results on get() method

Tags: laravel, get, sql-order-by

How do I use `orderBy` on this laravel query:

```
$comments = $ticket->comments()->get();
```

i used

```
$comments = $ticket->comments()->get()->orderBy('created_at');
```

but is not working.

The order should be descending

Comment: I think you have to set first the orderBy and then the get();

Comment: Thanks. I used $comments = $ticket->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get(); and its working

Answer (score 0):

You should put get() at the last. And the default order is **asc** so you should pass **desc** as parameter.

it would be:

```
$comments = $ticket->comments()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution